# Linux Delete Files Older Than and the Same Time Smaller Than

Tags: linux, find

I use this command to delete MP3 files older than 90 days.

```
find MP3/ -type f -name "*.mp3" -mtime +90 -delete
```

I want to make it delete those older than 3 days but with file size less than 100KB.

How to write the arguments for `< 100KB` and is `-size` good to go or should I use something else as as far as I know the file size itself is different that the size on the disk...

```
find MP3/ -type f -name "*.mp3" -mtime +3 -size xxx -delete
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, this does not delete files "older than 90 days". Most file systems do not store the creation time of the file, and this will simply find those files which were last modified 90+ days ago.  Perhaps this is mere pedantry, but believing that filesystems store creation time of the file is far too common and should be addressed whenever it rears its ugly head.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm already using it (on a Vicidial server) where all the files have the same creation/modify date as they are call recordings. It already works as needed, I just want to adapt it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using -size should be fine for your use case. The whole command would look like this:

```
find MP3/ -type f -name "*.mp3" -mtime +3 -size -100k -delete
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I thought -100k will be addressed as an argument like -name, -size ...